# my showRectangle class returns 0

Tags: java, class

I'm getting the following error message when run my Java class
`Error: Could not find or load main class Ex0603`

The code:

```
public class Circle{
    double Radius;
    Circle (double r)
    {
        Radius=Radius;
    }
    double getRadius()
    {
        double Radius;
        Radius=1.0;
        return Radius;
    }
    double getArea()
    {
        double Area;
        Area=Math.PI*Math.pow(Radius,2);
        return Area;
    }
    double getCircumference()
    {
        double Circumference;
        Circumference=Math.PI*(Radius*2);
        return Circumference;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the class that runs the main method? entry point to this.

Comment: `Radius = Radius` won't do a thing, you should do `Radius = r;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Class name is circle and you should save with it(circle.java)

You must ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. So, if its in the current folder then add . to your classpath. Note that the windows classpath separator is a semi-colon ie ;